# Show that a differentiable function $f$, where $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are integrable, has a value of $0$ when Lebesgue integrated over the real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and both $f(x)$ and $f^{\prime}(x)$ are integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.  Show $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{\prime}(x) \, dx = 0$.

I know that if $f^+$ and $f^-$ are the positive and negative parts of $f$, then

$$\int f = \int f^+ - \int f^-$$

Also, $|f| = f^+ + f^-$ so we know that $f$ is integrable iff $\int |f| < \infty$.

We can also treat the improper integral like so:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) \, dx + \int_{a}^{+\infty} f(x) \, dx$$

provided both integrals on the right converge.  I'm trying to take this information and formulate a proof out of it but it just won't come together.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JC , i believe integrable on $\mathbb R$ means the integral exists and is finite.

Comment: No, the problem is written as stated.

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$, for $x\neq 0$, $f(0)=1$, Does $f'$ integrable on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while and had not taken class this deep. but since integrateable on $R$ then $f(x)$ (exclude periodic the function) converge to 0 at $\infty$ and $-\infty$. So the $f(x)$ "travel up and down" was the same across the region. and follow this $\int f^\prime (x)dx=0$?

Comment: If it helps this problem refers to lebesgue integration and not riemann integration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is integrable, by the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://sos440.blogspot.kr/2017/02/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus.html) we have

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x) \mathbf{1}_{[a,b]}(x) \, dx = \int_{a}^{b} f'(x) \, dx = f(b) - f(a) $$

By the dominated convergence theorem, as $a\to-\infty$ and $b\to\infty$ the above quantity converges, from which we know that both

$$ \lim_{a\to-\infty} f(a) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \lim_{b\to\infty} f(b) $$

converge. Now by the integrability of $f$ it is easy to conclude that both must be zero. Therefore

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f'(x) \, dx = \left( \lim_{b\to\infty} f(b) \right) - \left( \lim_{a\to-\infty} f(a) \right)  = 0. $$

Comment: I just wonder, if in this case, $f$ has to be absolutely continuous on each $[a,b]$? Actually I wonder how do we prove the fundamental theorem of calculus here, initially I think of absolute continuity, but it is a loop. But your blog proves it, so it must be absolute continuous.

Comment: @user284331, That is a valid point, and indeed that is the most non-trivial part of this argument. We used the following result: if $f$ is *everywhere differentiable* on $[a, b]$ and its derivative is integrable, then $f$ is absolutely continuous. You can check a proof by following the link in my answer.

Comment: And this just makes me think of a little more. Can we really have an everywhere differentiable function on $[a,b]$ such that the Lebesgue integral of $f'$ on $[a,b]$ exists but not the Riemann?

Comment: @user284331, Perhaps [*Cantor-Volterra function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) is what you are seeking for. :)

Comment: Ah... today I have learnt something really big thing from you, thanks man.

Comment: @user284331 Glad it helped :)

Comment: @SangchulLee Just so I'm clear (undergrad...new at measure theory) you are saying that each limit on the endpoint converges to 0 not that there difference equals zero.  i.e. that the limit of f(b) as b approaches infinity equals 0, same with limit of f(a)

Comment: @IdleMathGuy, Yes, that is exactly what I am claiming.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee, here is another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714408/integration-by-parts-for-functions-not-n-times-continuously-differentibal) related to this differentiation issue, but I fail to give a good explanation to the OP because the usual setting of absolute continuity is about a closed interval, not of the form $(-\infty,y]$, would you mind to take a look of it?