# Integration by parts for functions not n times continuously differentibal?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue absolutely integrable function, define another function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $f(y_1,y_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{y_1}\int_{-\infty}^{y_2}g(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$. Another function $Q:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an infinitely differentiable and compactly supported function(a test function in $\mathbb{R}^2$). By Fubini's theorem, $f$ is well-defined, and it is continuous. I want to prove that 
$$\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}f(y_1,y_2)(\partial^2 Q/\partial y_1\partial y_2)dy_1dy_2=\int_R\int_Rg(y_1,y_2)Q(y_1,y_2)dy_1dy_2.$$
Indeed this is a simple step in Rudin's functional analysis Page 168 and Rudin just commented here "by integration by parts". I wonder why Rudin could use integration by parts here for $f$ not twice continuously differentible. Indeed I just know the following relevant result for integration by parts(in Terence Tao's Intro to measure theory): a function $h:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ is absolutely continuous, and a function $m:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ is differentiable and its first derivative is continuous(i.e., once continuously differentiable) with $m$ being compactly supported in $[a,b]$, then the second fundamental theorem of calculus implies $$\int_a^bhm'=-\int_a^bh'm$$. I have no idea to apply this result to the previous problem and how Rudin proves it just by using integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts in the context of definite integrals is nicely understood if you simply forget about differentiation. Indeed, it is just a classical rendition of the more general statement *Fubini's theorem*.

To see why, let us examine the classical case. Assume that $f$, $g$ are Lebesgue integrable on $[a, b]$. If we write $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) \, dt$ and $G(x) = \int_{a}^{x} g(t) \, dt$, then the integration by parts is proved in the following way:

\begin{align*}
\int_{a}^{b} F(x)g(x) \, dx
&= \int_{a}^{b} \left( \int_{a}^{x} f(t) \, dt \right) g(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{b} f(t)g(x)\mathbf{1}_{\{t < x \}} \, dtdx \\
&= \int_{a}^{b} \int_{a}^{b} f(t)g(x)\mathbf{1}_{\{t < x \}} \, dxdt \tag{Fubini} \\
&= \int_{a}^{b} f(t)(G(b) - G(t)) \, dt \\
&= F(b)G(b) - \int_{a}^{b} f(t) G(t) \, dt.
\end{align*}

For general constants of integration, it is straightforward to check that replacing $F$ and $G$ by $F + C_1$ and $G + C_2$, respectively, causes no harm to this formula. Combining this with the [fundamental theorem of calculus for absolutely continuous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions), we obtain

> **Proposition.** If $f$ and $g$ are absolutely continuous functions on $[a, b]$, then 
>   $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) g'(x) \, dx = [f(b)g(b) - f(a)g(a)] - \int_{a}^{b} f'(x)g(x) \, dx. $$

For your case, you can either utilize the above statement, or simply adopt the proof technique directly to establish the desired claim.

Comment: The panic point of OP question is that, how do we properly justify that $\dfrac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial y_{2}\partial y_{1}}=g(y_{1},y_{2})$? Even in the a.e. case. I found that it seems to me there is some dependency of a.e. set issue: It seems that at first we can have $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y_{1}}=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{y_{2}}g(y_{1},x_{2})dx_{2}$ a.e. but then this a.e. depends on $y_{2}$, no? And then we can perform like the second partial again to get $g(y_{1},y_{2})$? I am not entirely sure.

Comment: I think I know how to fix this issue. The point is to use weak derivative sense.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $M,N>0$ and let $F(y_{1},y_{2})=\displaystyle\int_{-M}^{y_{2}}\int_{-N}^{y_{1}}g(x_{1},x_{2})dx_{1}dx_{2}$. Also fix $c<d$, $a<b$. Now we have 
\begin{align*}
&\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})\int_{-M}^{y_{1}}\int_{-N}^{y_{2}}g(x_{1},x_{2})dx_{2}dx_{1}dy_{2}\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}F(y_{1},y_{2})\dfrac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}\\
&=F(y_{1},b)\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(y_{1},b)-F(y_{1},a)\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(y_{1},a)-\int_{a}^{b}\int_{-N}^{y_{1}}g(x_{1},y_{2})dx_{1}\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2},
\end{align*}
where we can choose $a<b$ such that the boundary vanishes, so
\begin{align*}
&\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})\int_{-M}^{y_{1}}\int_{-N}^{y_{2}}g(x_{1},x_{2})dx_{2}dx_{1}dy_{2}\\
&=-\int_{a}^{b}\int_{-N}^{y_{1}}g(x_{1},y_{2})dx_{1}\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}.
\end{align*}
Now we let $G(y_{1})=\displaystyle\int_{-N}^{y_{1}}g(x_{1},y_{2})dx_{1}$ (omitting the variable $y_{2}$), then
\begin{align*}
&\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})\int_{-M}^{y_{1}}\int_{-N}^{y_{2}}g(x_{1},x_{2})dx_{2}dx_{1}dy_{2}dy_{1}\\
&=-\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{-N}^{y_{1}}g(x_{1},y_{2})dx_{1}\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}dy_{1}\\
&=-\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}G(y_{1})\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}dy_{1}\\
&=-\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}G(y_{1})\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{1}dy_{2}\\
&=-\int_{a}^{b}\left[\left(G(d)\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(d,y_{2})-G(c)\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{1}}(c,y_{2})\right)-\int_{c}^{d}g(y_{1},y_{2})Q(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}\right]dy_{1},
\end{align*}
once again we choose $c<d$ such that the boundary vanishes, so
\begin{align*}
&\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})\int_{-M}^{y_{1}}\int_{-N}^{y_{2}}g(x_{1},x_{2})dx_{2}dx_{1}dy_{2}dy_{1}\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}g(y_{1},y_{2})Q(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}dy_{1}.
\end{align*}
Now use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to deduce that whenever $M,N\rightarrow\infty$, we have 
\begin{align*}
&\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})\int_{-\infty}^{y_{1}}\int_{-\infty}^{y_{2}}g(x_{1},x_{2})dx_{2}dx_{1}dy_{2}dy_{1}\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}g(y_{1},y_{2})Q(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}dy_{1}.
\end{align*}
Finally we note that 
\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})\int_{-\infty}^{y_{1}}\int_{-\infty}^{y_{2}}g(x_{1},x_{2})dx_{2}dx_{1}dy_{2}dy_{1}\\
&=\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{\partial^{2}Q}{\partial y_{1}\partial y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})\int_{-\infty}^{y_{1}}\int_{-\infty}^{y_{2}}g(x_{1},x_{2})dx_{2}dx_{1}dy_{2}dy_{1}\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}g(y_{1},y_{2})Q(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}dy_{1}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y_{1},y_{2})Q(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{2}dy_{1}
\end{align*}
for some $c<d,a<b$ by the assumption that $Q$ being compactly supported.

Comment: I still don't get the idea since if $\partial f/\partial y_1$ is only a.e the same as $\int_{-\infty}^{y_2}gdx_2$, then it is only a.e. determined. Why a a.e. determined function has derivatives? To make this clear supposing $f$ is on R and it has 0 for rational and 1 for irrational, then clearly f is a.e. the same as constant function 1, but f has no derivative at all at any point.

Comment: Actually that means, for fixed $y_{2}$, the first derivative of $f$ exists a.e. $y_{1}$ and is equal to the right-hand side. I have the issue that, the null set may depend on each fixed $y_{2}$, so then doing derivative again may cause some problem. I am not entirely sure of this, but the calculation, in a rough way, should be like that, there is no twice differentiable in issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally realize that differentiation is not necessary here, I see another more straighforward way to show this through approximating g by continuous function on $R^2$ and use the integration by parts technique for the case when g is continuous(without any problem).  The result is proven easily.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $f$ that is being used is $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} y_2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} y_1}f(y_1, y_2)$ (note the order), which we already know is $g(y_1, y_2)$, by the definition of $f$ and the (first part of the) fundamental theorem of calculus.  That is, the only twice differentiability in use is "once in each variable".